# Inject implementation using autofac to property or constructor

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a scenarios where instance of a third party library needs to be injected using autofac. Library does not expose implementation class, instead gives a factory to get an instance.

Example Code

```
public class DBConnection
{
     public IContext context { get; set; }
     public string GetConnection()
     {
         return context.GetConfiguration("connectionString");
     }
}
```

`IContext` is part of 3rd party lib and should be initialized using Autofac with `context = Configuration.Factory.GetContext();`. Ideally I can call this function in `DBConnection` constructor, but `IContext` is singleton, so better to get injected by DI container `IContext` implementation class is hidden so I can't register it using builder, returns implementation as interface

Answer (score 0):

You can add `IContext` as a dependency to `DbConnection`

```
public class DBConnection
{

    public DbConnection(IContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context; 
    }

    public IContext Context { get; }
    public String GetConnection()
    {
       return this.Context.GetConfiguration("connectionString");
    }
}
```

And then, you can register `IContext` like this :

```
builder.Register(c => Configuration.Factory.GetContext()).As<IContext>();
```